# Custom client-side aggregation in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

This question is similar to [Custom aggregation/grouping in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941674/custom-aggregation-grouping-in-jqgrid) but a little bit different.

I have the following jqGrid.

[image: First Grid]

It is loaded once and I'd like all of the following functionality to be done client side. The drop down is a selector that changes how to display the data.  Say for example I want to display by State, it should just show the State column (I can handle that through showing and hiding the columns), and I'd like it to aggregate/sum the "Number1", "Number2", and "Number3" columns as well.  It should look something like this (Hopefully my manual addition is correct).
[image: Second Grid]

I'd also need to be able to GET BACK to the first grid though so, 869 needs to broken back out into 285, 489, 95 values for Taylor Ridge, Skokie, Beecher.  Is this something that can be handled by jqGrid?

The following is the XML for the first grid, but I do have full control over how this XML is built so I can change that as necessary.

```
    <?xml version ='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<result>
  <row>
    <cell>1</cell>
    <cell>IL</cell>
    <cell>SPARLAND</cell>
    <cell>32</cell>
    <cell>61</cell>
    <cell>19</cell>
    <cell>0</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>2</cell>
    <cell>IL</cell>
    <cell>EDWARDS</cell>
    <cell>69</cell>
    <cell>56</cell>
    <cell>2</cell>
    <cell>0</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>2</cell>
    <cell>IL</cell>
    <cell>SPARLAND</cell>
    <cell>52</cell>
    <cell>30</cell>
    <cell>8</cell>
    <cell>0</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>2</cell>
    <cell>CA</cell>
    <cell>TAYLOR RIDGE</cell>
    <cell>285</cell>
    <cell>72</cell>
    <cell>15</cell>
    <cell>0</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>1</cell>
    <cell>CA</cell>
    <cell>SKOKIE</cell>
    <cell>489</cell>
    <cell>60</cell>
    <cell>12</cell>
    <cell>0</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>1</cell>
    <cell>CA</cell>
    <cell>BEECHER</cell>
    <cell>95</cell>
    <cell>46</cell>
    <cell>17</cell>
    <cell>0</cell>
  </row>
</result>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find your question interesting. Moreover because you spend almost all your reputation points for  the bounty I decided that you really need the solution of the problem. So I made [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomGrouping2.htm) for you. At the start it displays the full grid without grouping:

[image]

With respect of the select element you can choose the grouping column and receive as the result like

[image]

[image]

or

[image]

depend on the choice in the select element. If you choose "No grouping" the original view of the grid will be restored.

For the implementation I used `groupSummary` with the custom implementation of [summaryType](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping#summarytype).

I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622718/315935) additionally which describes how one can customize the summary row of the grouping.

The HTML code of body of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomGrouping2.htm) is

```html
<fieldset style="float:left" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-jqgrid">
    <select id="chooseGrouping">
        <option value="">No grouping</option>
        <option value="State">State</option>
        <option value="City">City</option>
        <option value="Level">Level</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
<div style="clear:left">
    <table id="grid"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

The corresponding the JavaScript code is below:

```js
var intTemplate = { formatter: 'integer', align: 'right', sorttype: 'int',
        summaryType: 'sum'},
    grouppingTemplate = {
        summaryType: function (val, name, record) {
            if (typeof (val) === "string") {
                return record[name];
            }
            return val;
        }
    },
    $grid = $("#grid");

$grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'CustomGrouping2.xml',
    height: 'auto',
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Level', formatter: 'integer', sorttype: 'int', template: grouppingTemplate },
        { name: 'State', template: grouppingTemplate },
        { name: 'City', template: grouppingTemplate },
        { name: 'Number1', template: intTemplate },
        { name: 'Number2', template: intTemplate },
        { name: 'Number3', template: intTemplate },
        { name: 'Selected', template: intTemplate }
    ],
    cmTemplate: { width: 90 },
    xmlReader: { root: 'result' },
    loadonce: true,
    rowNum: 1000,
    grouping: false,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: ['State'],
        groupSummary: [true],
        groupColumnShow: [true],
        groupText: ['{0}'],
        groupDataSorted: true,
        showSummaryOnHide: true
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        if (this.p.grouping) {
            $(this).children('tbody').children('tr').each(function () {
                var $tr = $(this);
                if (!$tr.hasClass('jqfoot')) {
                    $tr.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

$('#chooseGrouping').change(function () {
    var index, count, sel = $('option:selected', this).val(),
        allGroups = ["State", "City", "Level"];
    if (sel === "") {
        $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {grouping: false});
        for (index = 0, count = allGroups.length; index < count; index++) {
            $grid.jqGrid('showCol', allGroups[index]);
        }
    } else {
        $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {grouping: true, groupingView: {groupField: [sel]}});
        $grid.jqGrid('showCol', sel);
        index = $.inArray(sel, allGroups);
        if (index >= 0) {
            allGroups.splice(index, 1);
            for (index = 0, count = allGroups.length; index < count; index++) {
                $grid.jqGrid('hideCol', allGroups[index]);
            }
        }
    }
    $grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
});
```

Comment: this is definitely the answer I was looking for... but for one twist! :) If you notice in the screenshots above I'd also like for mutli-select to work.  Working through your example it's not as trivial as just adding multiselect: true.  Haven't had much luck figuring it out.  Any ideas?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @tk01: I didn't recognize that `multiselect: true` setting is really important for you because you don't wrote about this explicitly in the text. I think that one can try to solve the problem either be adding custom `summaryType` and custom formatter in the 'cb' column (like in [the answer](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomGrouping2.htm)) or add additional column having `formatter: 'checkbox', formatoptions: {disabled: false}` and add custom `summaryType` and probably also do custom formatter in the column. The column can simulate the selection. But the implementation of will be hard.

Comment: @tk01: One more way which I see is to create *one more* grid under the current grid. Fill the grid with the visible data after the grouping (see my asnwer) and then **hide** the grouped grid. In the way you will have the *standard* grid with the data which you need. So multiselect, sorting and *all other* features will be work.

Comment: Actually I just figured it out, it's not all the way there but I was able to get the checkbox added. Thanks again!

Comment: @tk01: It's fine it you could solve the problem yourself! You are welcome!