# Is it possible to modify the summaryType:'avg' function when grouping data?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am designing a grid which displays data by month depending on area division and then each division is broken down into teams using jqgrids group.

I want to display the average of all the teams in each division as the group summary for each division. I have set summaryType:'avg' for each column, however the average seems to include blank values, which I want it to ignore.

Is it possible to either modify the avg function to exclude blanks or even create my own?

Edit: As a side issue is it possible to then extract the summary data from the grid as I would like to generate graphs on the summary data for each division.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand you correctly. You don't posted and JavaScript code so I have to guess.

It's tricky, but it's possible to define `summaryType` as function. In the way you can implement any custom calculation.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622718/315935) provide an example how to implement `summaryType` as function. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422170/315935) do the same in case of usage of grouping summary.

Answer (score 0):

This is avg function example:

```
function avgFunc(val, name, record){
var v = parseFloat((record[name]||0));
var cnt = 1, vsum = v;
if (val) {
    cnt += val.cnt;
    vsum += val.vsum;
    v = vsum/cnt;
}
val = new Number(v);
val.vsum = vsum;
val.cnt = cnt;
return val;
}
```