# Is Multi Grouping in JqGrid Currently supported?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jqgrid

I am currently trying to implement multi grouping in jqGrid but can't seem to get it right. 
See code below:

```
colNames:['Programme','Course', 'Fee Type','Description','Apply', 'Amount', 'Discount', 'Discounted Amt','GATE Amount'], 
                    colModel:[ 
                        {name:'programme',index:'programme', width: 25}, 
                        {name:'moduleInstance',index:'moduleInstance', width:30
                        },
                        {name:'feeType',index:'feeType', width:15
                        },                           
                        {name:'description',index:'description', width:15
                        },
                        {name:'isApplicable',index:'isApplicable', width:4, editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"True:False"},formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false} 
                        },
                        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:5
                        },                   
                        {name:'discount',index:'discount', width:5, editable:true},
                        {name:'discountAmount',index:'discountAmount', width:8},
                        {name:'gateAmountCovered',index:'gateAmountCovered', width:8, editable:true}
                    ],sortname: 'moduleInstance',
                    grouping:true,
                    groupingView : {
                        groupField : ['programme', 'moduleInstance'],
                        groupColumnShow : [false, false],
                        groupText : ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>', '{0}']
                    },
```

This only shows programme title on the header and not the other. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I never implemented grouping, but i tried this code in my example and got the same result that you got. Then i looked into google and found [this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/multilevel-grouping-in-jqgrid/)

This is a very old post, in 2011 but i suppose they are right, its not supported. that's why they would have come up with this multipleGroup approach. Look into [this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/multi-level-groupingaggregation/) and this [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941674/custom-aggregation-grouping-in-jqgrid). At least you will get some references.